# how can I set value for $stateParam in my controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my controller I am trying to go to a different state in my angularapplication:

```
$state.go('customer.items',{factory:'factA'}});
```

My state from the route.js file looks like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('customer.items', {
  url: '/items/:factory',
  resolve: {
    items: [
      '$q', '$stateParams', 'car', function($q, $stateParams, car) {
        var deferred, f, s;
        deferred = $q.defer();
        debugger;
        s = function(data) {
          return deferred.resolve(data);
        };
        f = function() {
          return deferred.reject();
        };
        car.all($stateParams.factory).then(s, f);
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    ]
  },
  views: {
    'tableView': {
      templateUrl: "templates/views/customer_items.html",
      controller: 'itemscontroller'
    }
  }
});
```

When I debug this code $stateParams.factory is '' instead of 'factA'? How can I set this factory property in $stateParams coming from the controller?

Comment: Create a plunker to reproduce. I tried it and it works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/6QIaYK7MqjYPoD8bljOC?p=preview

Comment: I can't see any problem there either

Comment: $state.go('customer.items',{factory:'factA'}}); maybe you paste one more } there? i don't think you real code has this problem